javascript: does the iterator returned by Map.prototype.entries() have .filter as a property?
I have an ES6 Map and I'd like to iterate over it's key-value pairs.
MDN (if I'm understanding it correctly) says that when I call .entries() on my map, I get an Iterator.  Further, MDN says that all iterators (including the one returned by .entries()  inherit from Iterator.prototype and that that class has a .filter method.
But in the project I'm currently working on, when I write
myMap.entries().filter(...)

where myMap is an ES6 Map, my typescript says "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'IterableIterator'".
Who's right?  MDN or Typescript?
Actually, to be fair to Typescript (and MDN!), I probably just wrote the typehint wrong when I set up my map. I used the typehint:
Map<string,boolean>

(because the keys in my Map are strings and the values are booleans.)
So, to refine my question, which of the following is true?

MDN is wrong
Typescript is wrong
I wrote the wrong type hint

Thanks!

check your browser compatibilty. or nodejs it asks for v 22

Can you share your tsconfig here? I suspect that might be the reason for it erroring.

No iterators do. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers is still not finalized. MDN tells you as much.

MDN shows a big blue notice box at the top: "Experimental: This is an experimental technology. Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production." See also node.green

A MDN mentions it, Iterator.prototype.filter() is experimental;
Typescript rarely provides the typing for experimental APIs. So while it might work, TS will indicate (depending on the target) if this actually an API you can/should use.
